# How to give redirect experience in MSAL client side login in Angular?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, msal.js, msal-angular

I am working on Angular using `@azure/msal-angular` npm and i am able to login to the system. Now, my requirement is how to make redirect experience instead of pop-up when i click login button.

TIA.

Answer (score 3):

Please set `navigateToLoginRequestUrl: false` in your 'auth' config if you do not want to return to the page that initiated the request.

For more information about navigateToLoginRequestUrl, see [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/2978#issuecomment-774295687).